# python gensim: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python, gensim

I have a small python pipeline. One class cleans and lemmatizes the data.
It returns a List of Lists of Strings (i.e., `List[List[str]]`). I then pass the list on to another class which passes the data to gensim dictionary

The following code, however, throws this exception:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(self.bowlist)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'bowlist'
```

Code:

```
from typing import List
import re
from gensim import corpora

class ListOfListsToGensimCorpora:
    def __init__(self, bow_list: List[List[str]]):
        self.bowlist = bow_list

    def perform(self):
        dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(self.bowlist)
        print(dictionary)
```

I am new to Python but I have checked through debug and other methods, bowlist is a List[List[str]].

Comment: `lists` do not have any `bowlist` attribute. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I pass List[List[str]] as a field variable. I simply name it bowlist. Then I pass the List[List[str]] to gensim corpora. It does not recognize that it is a List[List[str]]....I guess. Or I am misunderstanding the input param for corpora.Dictionary

Comment: The class definition is fine. To use the class, simply do something like: `foo = [["abcd", "efgh"], ["ijkl", "mnop"]]` `bar = ListOfListsToGensimCorpora(foo)`, then `bar.perform()` gives `Dictionary(4 unique tokens: ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop'])`

Comment: When calling the method, you should not pass self into an already instantiated class (mostly). So `dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(self.bowlist)` will give an error outside a class definition.

Comment: @Xero Smith Thanks a million. The error was indeed in the way I instantiated the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using like that?

```
ListOfListsToGensimCorpora.perform(bow_list)
```

it is fine with this:

```
l = ListOfListsToGensimCorpora(bow_list)
l.perform()
```

or change you code by this?

```
from typing import List
import re
from gensim import corpora

class ListOfListsToGensimCorpora:
    def __init__(self, bow_list: List[List[str]]):
        self.bowlist = bow_list
        self.perform()  # run perform when instantiuation 

    def perform(self):
        dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(self.bowlist)
        print(dictionary)
```